# 'Rule 0' questions and their variants

Tags: discussion, comments

This seems to come up regularly when a question is raised relating to the balance of power between the GM and players. What invariably happens is that people all have different interpretations of this, often based on how a particular game's rules are phrased.

This often leads to long discussions in comments, which I always understood was not the ideal way of doing things.

Are we handling these questions the best way? Is there a 'correct' answer that can be given with this type of issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's called "refrain from arguing in comments."

Differing interpretations are fine.  Someone who has a Rule 0 answer should post it, someone who doesn't believe in that should post that, and then voting etc. will make the most helpful answers rise to the top. Usually someone who pauses to rub their two brain cells together will make an answer that incorporates both options, and they win.

If you disagree with someone - post a competing answer, or live with the pain.

Comment: Agreed. I think there's so much arguing over these questions and their answers only because it's the friction point of some of the larger, incompatible RPG cultures. We can't handle these any better than we already are, except by personally not engaging in turf wars in comments. (Speaking from experience as a guilty party.)

Comment: I disagree with this comment.